# Very odd issue with Ruby and regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am getting completely different reults from string.scan and several regex testers...

I am just trying to grab the domain from the string, it is the last word.

The regex in question:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)*\w{1,4}$/
```

The string (1 single line, verified in Ruby's runtime btw)

```
str = 'Show more results from software.informer.com'
```

Work fine, but in ruby....

```
irb(main):050:0> str.scan /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)*\w{1,4}$/
=> [["informer."]]
```

I would think that I would get a match on software.informer.com  ,which is my goal.

Comment: Not an answer, but take a look at http://rubular.com/ , it's great to test regex. http://rubular.com/regexes/13669

Comment: Thanks.. I thought it was giving me inconsistent results but it was just my unfamiliarity with string.scan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look as if you expect more than one result (especially as the regex is anchored). In that case there is no reason to use scan.

```
'Show more results from software.informer.com'[ /([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)*\w{1,4}$/ ]
#=> "software.informer.com"
```

If you do need to use scan (in which case you obviously need to remove the anchor), you can use `(?:)` to create non-capturing groups.

```
'foo.bar.baz lala software.informer.com'.scan( /(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)*\w{1,4}/ )
#=> ["foo.bar.baz", "lala", "software.informer.com"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is correct, the result has to do with the way String#scan behaves. From [the official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812):

"If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group."

Basically, if you put parentheses around the whole regex, the first element of each array in your results will be what you expect.

Comment: Interesting... but to me, parenthess seems unavoidable, and yet affect the way scan works. Any tips...?

Comment: Parentheses here are a little confusing because they have two distinct functions: grouping a sub-expression for repetition, and forming the output of `scan`. One could fix this by introducing another symbol for controlling scan's output, but I think the parentheses usually work pretty well (you often end up with what you want, naturally) and introducing externally-dependent (method-related) symbols into regular expressions does not seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a match on `software.informer.com`. Check the value of `$&`. The return of `scan` is an array of the captured groups. Add capturing parentheses around the suffix, and you'll get the `.com` as part of the return value from `scan` as well.

The regex testers and Ruby are not disagreeing about the fundamental issue (the regex itself). Rather, their interfaces are differing in what they are emphasizing. When you run `scan` in `irb`, the first thing you'll see is the **return value** from `scan` (an Array of the captured subpatterns), which is not the same thing as the matched text. Regex testers are most likely oriented toward displaying the matched text.

Comment: Hm, I'm new to regex :/... but I still don't get why the regex testers and ruby vary, even the "ruby regex tester" is failing me.  Hm, and also I want 1 match, not several. This method gets me more matches...?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this :

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.*\w{1,4})$/
```

This returns

```
informer.com
```

On your test string.

http://rubular.com/regexes/13670